# Generalize [Dockerfile] to [Containerfile], for now and the future․

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

[image: Docker to Buildah and Podman]

The description of the tag [dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dockerfile) says “A Dockerfile is a file containing instructions to build a Docker image” ⸺ Yes, it *was* right, but nowadays Dockerfiles are not specific to Docker. Dockerfiles also work with Buildah & Podman (and there might be other ones in the future) and [they have generalized the naming](https://github.com/containers/buildah/issues/1853): “***Containerfile***.”

If there’s any questions with this tag that are particularly specific to Docker, they would have been tagged with [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) as well, so they won’t lose the information.

I suggest retagging [dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dockerfile) to [containerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/containerfile), or creating the new tag as a synonym.

Comment: Are there many dockerfile questions that need to refer to the Docker-specific variant for some reason? Phrased another way: Are we *losing important information* on some questions if we convert [dockerfile] to the more generic equivalent?

Comment: @zcoop98 Docker-specific questions, if any, would have been tagged with [tag:docker] as well.

Comment: [Docker suffers from the `Xerox` problem](https://simplystatedbusiness.com/brand/). Like it or not the industry refers to them as `Dockerfile`s.

Comment: FYI, there is already [tag:container-file]

Comment: @TylerH That tag doesn't seem to be related to this kind of container based on its usage, but then again, there are only 4 questions in the tag.

Comment: New question: Are "containerfiles" 100% identical to dockerfiles? Are they the same? Or are there technical differences?

Comment: @zcoop98 They are 100% identical; just different names. From [`podman-build`](http://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-build.1.html): “Builds an image using instructions from one or more `Containerfile`s or `Dockerfile`s and a specified build context directory. **A `Containerfile` uses the same syntax as a `Dockerfile` internally.** For this document, **a file referred to as a `Containerfile` can be a file named either ‘`Containerfile`’ or ‘`Dockerfile`’.**”

Comment: @zcoop98 Yeah, I mostly am just pointing out there's no way we can have a [tag:containerfile] tag when there is already a [tag:container-file] tag, that means something completely different...

Comment: I don't even know why we have a separate tag for the file. The only one that interprets that file meaningfully it's docker, literally no one care about it. Docker is the only consumer of it, so tagging your question with docker should be enough. In fact, I doubt there would be on topic questions about the file itself.

Comment: @Braiam Did you read the question or comments above? “The only one that interprets that file meaningfully is Docker.” **is false.** Buildah and Podman also do it. **If it works with Docker, it should work with Buildah & Podman as well, and vice versa.** That’s why I’m trying to generalize it.

Comment: They do not _meaningfully consume it_. Buildah just mashes string together to "generate" the file. That's not consumption, that's production. Podman is less bad, it imports moby libraries to manage the docker daemon (along with kubernetes, etc), so it arguably consumes it meaningfully (if only to pass the task to moby later). But that still doesn't clear the biggest hurdle: there's nothing inherently programming about a Dockerfile.

Comment: @Braiam If it has nothing to do with programming, why does the tag [tag:dockerfile] even exist in SO, then, remaining not burninated?

Comment: Well, because we must tackle the [tag:web] first,  also the [tag:website], also [tag:username], etc. if you catch my drift ;) Note: the presence or absence of a tag doesn't assure you that you can ask questions about that topic on SO. Programming is on topic on SO, but there's no tag for it.

Comment: @Braiam As you said with your [tag:web], [tag:website], and [tag:username] examples, just because “There’s nothing inherently programming about a Dockerfile” doesn’t mean the tag should not exist in SO, right. And the same logic applies to the tag [tag:containerfile]. It might have “the biggest hurdle” to be on-topic in SO, but it can’t be the rationale for not creating the new tag, to rename the existing, or, as a synonym.

Answer (score 8):

...no.

Docker and Dockerfile is still a household name, and it's one of those things that I still Google and look up when trying to troubleshoot or build my Docker containers.

Once "Containerfile" starts becoming less of a whisper and more of the topic, then *perhaps* we can talk about a synonym.  But definitely not ***now***.

Answer (score 6):

**I don't think a new tag makes sense here, at least not yet.**

For one, there's already a [container-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/container-file) tag, which is likely too close to "Containerfile" for it to be its own tag.

Second, if there is no useful distinction between Containerfiles and Dockerfiles, then a new [containerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/containerfile) tag would just be a direct synonym of [dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dockerfile), which isn't useful either, unless containerfile is a particularly common name (which might make it useful as a signpost of sorts).

In general, tag renames should be dictated more by actual usage than by an organization proposing a rename (even with Docker being part of the Open Container Initiative). If Docker came out and decided they were renaming their files to this new name, it might make sense to rename the tag, but this doesn't appear to be at that level (at least not yet).

---

Here's some data I pulled together about this and related/ mentioned tags. It didn't end up being incredibly relevant, but I pulled it together, so I'll put it here anyway.

### [dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dockerfile) Usage

- 10,548 total questions
- 9,532 (90%) questions are also tagged [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker)
- *1* question tagged [buildah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buildah)
- *4* tagged [podman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/podman)
- *0* tagged [rkt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rkt) (Docker alternative)
- *0* tagged [lxd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lxd) (Docker alternative)

<sub>[(SEDE Query)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?TagName=dockerfile)</sub>

### Related Tags

| Tag | Total Q's | Most Used Accompanying Tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) | 97,452 Qs | 1. [docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-compose) - 17,912 Qs 2. [dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dockerfile) - 9,532 Qs 3. [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) - 5,803 Qs <sup>[(SEDE Query)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?TagName=docker)</sup> |
| [buildah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buildah) | 27 Qs | 1. [podman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/podman) - 13 Qs 2. [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) - 10 Qs 3. [containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/containers) - 7 Qs <sup>[(SEDE Query)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?TagName=buildah)</sup> |
| [podman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/podman) | 193 Qs | 1. [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) - 56 Qs 2. [containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/containers) - 46 Qs 3. [buildah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buildah) - 13 Qs <sup>[(SEDE Query)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?TagName=podman)</sup> |
| [rkt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rkt) | 43 Qs | 1. [coreos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coreos) - 21 Qs 2. [kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) - 15 Qs 3. [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) - 11 Qs <sup>[(SEDE Query)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?TagName=rkt)</sup> |
| [lxd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lxd) | 132 Qs | 1. [lxc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lxc) - 67 Qs 2. [ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) - 20 Qs 3. [containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/containers) - 19 Qs <sup>[(SEDE Query)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?TagName=lxd)</sup> |
| [container-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/container-file) | 4 Qs | (Not useful with only 4 questions, but no questions or accompanying tags are related to the Docker-type of containerization) |